# Async library best practice: ConfigureAwait(false) vs. setting the synchronization context

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

It's well-known that in a general-purpose library, `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used on every await call to avoid continuing on the current SynchronizationContext.

As an alternative to peppering the entire codebase with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, one could simply set the SynchronizationContext to null once, at the public surface method, and restore it before returning to the user. In other words:

```
public async Task SomeSurfaceMethod()
{
    var callerSyncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    try
    {
        // Do work
    }
    finally
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(callerSyncCtx);
    }
}
```

This could also be wrapped in a `using` for better readability.

Is there a disadvantage to this approach, does it not end up producing the same effect?

The major advantage is obviously readability - the removal of all `ConfigureAwait(false)` calls. It may also reduce the likelihood of forgetting a `ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere (although analyzers mitigate this, and it could be argued that developers could just as well forget changing the SynchronizationContext).

A somewhat exotic advantage is not embedding the choice of capturing the SynchronizationContext or not in all methods. In other words, in one case I may want to run method X with a SynchronizationContext, while in another I may want to run the same method without one. When `ConfigureAwait(false)` is embedded everywhere that isn't possible. Granted, this is quite a rare requirement, but I bumped into it while working on Npgsql (triggering this question).

Comment: And what about `SomeSurfaceMethod(keepInContext bool) {await asyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(keepInContext)}` simple and allows caller to choice...

Comment: @jlvaquero the problem is that await calls *within* `asyncMethod` have to also specify `ConfigureAwait`, so you have to pass `keepInContext` all the way via the stack. Seems rather clunky vs. setting SynchronizationContext just once at the surface level...

Comment: You argue that this adds readability but initially it will not - for anyone new to your codebase, they'll find code that's obviously "broken" because it's not using `ConfigureAwait`, which is what they've learned to do when writing library code. I haven't got an answer yet to your question but I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever while that's a valid point, it's the case whenever any sort of change is proposed... The fact that people are used to one practice isn't really an argument against changing it...

Comment: Check the links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776408/c-sharp-async-await-chaining-with-configureawaitfalse

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305968/use-task-run-in-synchronous-method-to-avoid-deadlock-waiting-on-async-method/28307965#28307965

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks for the links, they indeed discuss the same approach. Nobody seems to have commented on any disadvantage until now.

Comment: Check this link too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518980/using-configureawaitfalse-for-private-async-methods

As Stephen Cleary suggest, both are the valid mechanism, Idea remains, you can go for either way and there will not be any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MrinalKamboj wrote in the comments, the approach of temporarily setting the SynchronizationContext to null at the public surface method and setting back has already been proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305968/use-task-run-in-synchronous-method-to-avoid-deadlock-waiting-on-async-method/28307965#28307965). There doesn't seem to be any specific problem associated with this (see [Stephen Cleary's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519539/640325)).