# Using Tasks in a non async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am implementing a run() function that **can not** be async. The goal is to send a get request to a server, and then download some files based on the result of the get request and return the number of files downloaded. I have written an async function to do that but I want to essentially "await" it before the rest of my main function continues. I am unable to achieve this behavior currently as the function just hangs. Not sure why its hanging :(

I think I just need some insights into Task and why this isn't working as expected. I am familiar with promises in JS so I thought this wouldn't be that difficult.

Thank you!

```
public int run(){
    FilesManager test = new FilesManager();
    string path = Path.Combine("C:\Users\username\Documents", "Temp");
    Task<int> T_count = test.Downloadfiles(path); //TODO: trying to "await" this before the messageBoxes
    Task.WaitAll(T_count);
    int count = T_count.Result;
    MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded");
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
}

public async Task<int> Downloadfiles(string path)
{
    String[] response = await getClient.GetFromJsonAsync<string[]>("http://localhost:3000");
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (string url in response)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            var response2 = await getClient.GetAsync(uri);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(
                path + counter.ToString(),
                FileMode.Create))
            {
                await response2.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        while (e != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
        return 0;
    }         
}
```

**EDIT:**
Still not able to get the task.WaitAll(T_count) to work. With some more debugging, the execution jumps from the response2 = await getClient.GetAsync... straight into the waitAll, never hitting the copyToAsync or counter++.

Comment: What's preventing your run function from being async?

Comment: `WebClient ` <-- ew. [Don't use `WebClient`, use `HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient) - and if you can't use `HttpClient` because it's `async`-only then use `HttpWebRequest` (it's not as nice as `HttpClient` but it's still miles better than `WebClient`).

Comment: It just has to be sync for the plugin I am building. The Api requires a synchronous run function

Comment: @AriBaranian You can always run async methods in the thread-pool and use .NET's synchronization primitives to _safely_ wait until it's completed - or schedule it in the background and return immediately, assuming you'll be able to check-in on it in future.

Comment: @Dai I will look into HTTPClient for the file download. I am already using it for the "getClient" in my code but saw that webclient had a really easy way to do file download. But is that what is causing my problem? is the run() function set up correctly otherwise?

Comment: Take a look at what mister Cleary has to say about this: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm surprised he hasn't shown-up in this thread in-person yet...

Comment: Consider using the AsyncEx library. Cleary is very good for this kind of stuff. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-thread-pool-hack

Answer (score 1):

Sync-over-async is a fundamentally difficult problem, because you need to guarantee that continuations never try to run on the thread you are blocking on, otherwise you will get a deadlock as you have seen. Ideally you would [never block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but sometimes that is not possible.

`Task.Run(...)..GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is normally fine to use for this purpose, although there are still some circumstances when it can deadlock.

Do *not* call the UI from inside the `async` function, therefore you must move the `catch` with `MessageBox.Show` to the outer function.

You can also make this more efficient, by using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, and you are missing a `using` on the `response2` object.

```cs
public int run()
{
    FilesManager test = new FilesManager();
    string path = Path.Combine("C:\Users\username\Documents", "Temp");
    
    try
    {
        int count = Task.Run(() => test.Downloadfiles(path)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded");
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        return count;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        while (e != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public async Task<int> Downloadfiles(string path)
{
    String[] response = await getClient.GetFromJsonAsync<string[]>("http://localhost:3000");
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (string url in response)
        {
            using (var response2 = await getClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            using (var fs = new FileStream(
                path + counter.ToString(),
                FileMode.Create))
            {
                await response2.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }         
}
```

Another option is to remove and afterwards restore the `SynchronizationContext`, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307965/14868997).

Comment: I thought using `Task.Run(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` was only safe if you use `StartNew`  with some non-default `TaskCreationOptions` values... but I might be getting confused..

Comment: @Dai Then again, I might be getting confused also. Like I said, it's *hard*.